# Consulta con multiples relaciones en laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql, relaciones

Estoy haciendo una consulta donde necesito obtener los equipos que pertenecen a una denominación y una unidad dadas. Tengo los siguientes modelos.

- **Denominacion** (tiene caracteristicas, y equipos a través de caracteristica)
- **Caracteristica** (pertenece a denominacion, y tiene equipos)
- **Unidad** (tiene departamentos, y equipos a través de departamentos)
- **Departamento** (pertenece a unidad, y tiene equipos)
- **Equipo** (pertenece a caracteristica y a departamento)

Con el sgte. codigo obtengo los equipos que pertenecen a una denominacion:

```
$equipos = Denominacion::find($denominacion_id)->equipos()->withTrashed()->get();
```

Necesito que solo sean los que pertenecen a la unidad con id `unidad_id`

Comment: Agrega por favor tus modelos y las relaciones declaradas en cada uno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres los equipos que pertenezcan a una denominación y que también pertenezcan a una unidad, yo haría una intersección (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections#method-intersect):

```php
$equipos_denom = Denominacion::find($denominacion_id)->equipos()->withTrashed()->get();
$equipos_unidad = Unidad::find($unidad_id)->equipos()->withTrashed()->get();
$equipos_comunes = $equipos_denom->intersect($equipos_unidad);
```

Comment: Y la denominación se perdió?

Comment: Edito la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias. Estupenda tu respuesta. Aproveché y lei todo el capítulo, era una asignatura pendiente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar condiciones a las relaciones. Puedes intentar algo asi

```
$equipos = Denominacion::find($denominacion_id)->equipos
->where('denominacion_id',$denominacion_id)
->withTrashed()->get();
```